# how to integrate mule mmc with active directory

Tags: active-directory, mule

i am not able to integrate `mule mmc` with `Active directory` below are connection parameters I am using:

`providerURL=ldap://192.168.1.14:389/ userDn=cn=CN=serviceaccount,OU=Privileged Accounts,OU=VIBE,DC=gamma,DC=rb,DC=net password=mmcadmin usernameAttribute=sAMAccountName userSearchBaseContext=ou=OU=VIBE,DC=gamma,DC=rb,DC=net userSearchFilterExpression=(sAMAccountName={0}) userSearchBase=OU=VIBE,DC=gamma,DC=rb,DC=net userSearchAttributeKey=objectclass userSearchAttributeValue=user roleDn=OU=Groups,DC=gamma,DC=rb,DC=net groupSearchFilter=(member={0})`

Comment: i assume you looked at the docs? https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-management-console/v/3.8/setting-up-and-managing-users-via-ldap

Comment: thanks , i have looked at the doc but not able to get what i need to give in user serch base context nad user search base

Answer (score 0):

```
Configuration:
<ldap:config name="LDAP_Configuration" authDn="CN=Test Test,DC=zone,DC=xxx,DC=net" url="LDAP://zone.xxx.net" doc:name="LDAP: Configuration" authentication="simple" authPassword="PASSW0RD$"/>

XML For LDAP in Flow:
  <ldap:search config-ref="LDAP_Configuration" baseDn="OU=USERS,OU=PUN,OU=VIBE,DC=zone,DC=xxx,DC=net" filter="(&amp;(sn=Cena)&amp;(givenName=John))" scope="SUB_TREE" structuralObjectClass="user" doc:name="LDAP">
  <ldap:attributes>
                <ldap:attribute>mail</ldap:attribute>
                <ldap:attribute>samAccountName</ldap:attribute>
            </ldap:attributes>
 </ldap:search>
```